# iOS - How to download needed interval of .mov(H.264 AVC) from public storage (save on phone e.g. only from 53sec to 60 sec)

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-video

I know it's a challenging question, but I can't find suggestions on the internet.

.mov files(h.264 avc) are big(especially 4K resolution) but extremely slow to download(due to that storage) and user of application needs only part of it. Please help to find the solution for getting metadata of the file; download to the device only needed part, and save it locally as the new .mov file.

Thanks in advance.